# Laravel Mail::send() inside a loop

Tags: php, email, laravel, swiftmailer

Can I safely use `Mail::send()` inside a loop with 1000 repetitions?

I mean there is probably problem with using php `mail()` inside such a loop because it is said that it opens a SMTP socket for each call but what about laravel `Mail::send()`?

**update: The loop itself is inside a queue job.**

Comment: Use `Mail::later` to queue them all up.

Comment: @JosephSilber The loop itself is inside a queue job

Comment: Doesn't matter. You still don't want to do it all in one shot.

Comment: @JosephSilber Ok It seems a good idea, thanks

Comment: Agree with @JosephSilber most likely a lot of the messages with get blocked and your IP address added to blacklists if you send that many close together.

Comment: try with `Mail::queue`

Comment: Depends on what SMTP service you are using (Mandrill I'm guessing?) – you shouldn't be penalized for using a loop coupled with an SMTP-service. But no, Mail::send() does not open/close it's connection after each send if you are running the queue as a daemon. But I would probably still use Mail::queue() or Mail::later() just not to have a heavy operation in that many cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the job itself in the queue on its own with a loop (which can cause that job to timeout depending on your queue configuration):

Queue up each email one-by-one using `Mail::queue`. This way, for instance you'll have 100 emails in the queue each one running one-by-one until the queue is empty.

Its also a good idea to have a way of managing / logging failed queue jobs so that you can see which ones have failed: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs